# CSS class is not applying to div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code with class `.1-html` and div

CSS:

```
.1-html {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="1-html">
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: You should read first "[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @Killer Johan I posted a correct solution to your problem , did that work for you ?

Answer (score 4):

A name should begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-) or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers.  if the first character is a hyphen, the second character must be a letter or underscore, and the name must be at least 2 characters long.

Checkout details at [How to name a css class](http://bdavidxyz.com/blog/how-to-name-css-classes/) and [css selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html)

Below code should work or check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7oaqbjpo/).

**CSS:**

```
.html-1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="html-1">
</div>
```

**If you want to use number at the starting of the class name then follow the code below or check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8851wy5p/):**

**CSS:**

```
[class="1html"] {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="1html">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about hyphen thingy. Just a small **correction**: if the first character is a hyphen, the second character must be a letter, *hyphen* or underscore. Essentially, if CSS class name is beginning with hyphen then a digit can't be the second character.

Comment: So `--h` is a valid CSS class name.

Comment: Yes! --h is valid CSS class name

Comment: you can use names starting with number for classes in css , you just need to modify just a bit of how to use the class

Comment: @SagarBhattacharya updated the answer for the classes starting with number.

Comment: @SagarBhattacharya made it work but to do things that way is still invalid HTML. Never, EVER do this!

Answer (score 1):

Names starting with number are invalid in CSS so you need to escape the number.

Try this block of code , it's working in my browser

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" lang="en">
<style>

    [class="1-html"]  {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="1-html">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot of web browser]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I tried it. I also tried `className` with both  `"\1-html"` and `"1-html"` after making the changes suggested by you but it has no effect. Black border isn't appearing for the div.

Comment: then you can use this [class="1-html"]  {/*your style*/}  . I have modified the answer you can re-try it and added my browser screenshot with updated code

Comment: Yep. Your updated answer works. I've updated your answer to reflect the correct part.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you got it to "work". Invalid HTML is still invalid HTML and shouldn't be used at all! Browsers are required to do the best they can with broken and invalid markup.

Comment: @Rob even if it is invalid but we need to have a fix , for example if someone has to have the class name starting with number because of their backend api or some dynamic content which is the basis of their html structure there need to have some workaround

Comment: Invalid HTML is an **error**! Having errors in markup is a blunder! Anything used to fix it is a hack! It's undefined and has unpredictable, unreliable behavior! You should be embarrassed and not trying to find excuses. I hope you don't build airplanes.